# How can I test for spaces in the path and give an appropriate error?

Tags: maven-2, maven

I am trying to write an integration test POM for our project.  We've got the project downloading and installing/unzipping appropriately (using the maven-dependency-plugin), but one caveat of our project is that it can't yet run in paths that have spaces in them.  I'm looking for a very simple way to evaluate ${project.build.directory} and throw a human readable error if it contains spaces.  I'd like this to happen BEFORE downloading dependencies, since this takes quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it with the help of antrun plugin and `<contains>` condition.

```
<build>
  <plugins>                       
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.6</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>validate</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <target>
              <fail message="project.build.directory(${project.build.directory}) contains spaces">
                <condition>
                  <contains string="${project.build.directory}" substring=" "/>
                </condition>
              </fail>
            </target>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I've been told my the maven-philes to avoid the antrun plugin like the plague...  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jared. You may write 20-times more lines and create a custom rule for `maven-enforcer-plugin`. http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html.  BTW, what's the objection to antrun?  Looks to me like the right tool for the right purpose here.

Comment: I personally don't have objections to the antrun plugin, but there are those (including those in my company) who want to avoid using it if at all possible because it is often used to hack things in a very non-maven-esque way.  If nobody comes up with another way I'll mark your answer as the accepted one.